Issues with Large File Uploads on Firebase Hosting
I am currently working with Firebase and have a small API hosted there. Recently, I also deployed a front-end built with Nuxt.js using Firebase App Hosting.
Everything was functioning well until I started implementing file uploads. Uploading two files (around 30MB total) works perfectly. However, when I attempt to upload four or more files (approximately 60MB), the process fails.
The issue: When I trigger the POST endpoint from the front-end, it never reaches the API. Instead, a 500 Internal Server Error is thrown somewhere along the way.
What's weird is that there are no related logs indicating what went wrong. Or, at least, I couldn't find them.
Even more confusing is that if I run the front-end locally, I can upload up to 8 files (around 120MB total) without any issues. The same code fails once it is deployed to the server.
I am at a loss as to what could be causing this issue or what steps to take to debug it.
Here is the upload method in the front-end, in case it helps:
const uploadFiles = async () => {
    console.log("Uploading files session started...");

    try {
        console.log("Preparing to parse files...");

        const formData = new FormData();
        files.value.forEach((file) => {
            formData.append("files", file);
        });

        console.log("Files parsed, token retrieved. Uploading files...");

        uploadSessionId.value = await $fetch("/api/upload-files", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`
            },
            body: formData
        });

        console.log("Files uploaded");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error uploading files:", error);
    }
};

The console output is something like

Uploading files session started...
Preparing to parse files...
Files parsed, token retrieved. Uploading files...
Error uploading files: 500 (Internal Error)

The API EP is never hit.

Guess there is an innate limitation of a browser as of how much you can send via HTTP to a server in one go. Try sending it by waves, one at a time. Might be an API limit but mostly outside of that scope.

@kissu but then it wouldn't work doing the same thing from the dev environment, right? Is there any way i can find out what's the actual issue?

Local dev environment is not the same and might not be subject to the same limitations IMO. You'll need to look around the Internet about topics related. Ask on Firebase's side otherwise.
